# Determine corresponding field names of items in Request.Files?

Tags: asp.net

Given a set of uploaded files in **Request.Files**, how do figure out which form field yielded which file?

I have a generic form emailer that various forms post to. This file generates an email of the name/value pairs contained in the form post. I'm trying to add support for uploaded files such that the table of name/value pairs will show the name of the file upload element and the name that the file was saved as.

However, I can't figure out how to link that information together. HttpPostedFile doesn't contain any information about the HTTP request (like which field name was used), and Request.Form doesn't contain any entries for uploaded files.

So while I can easily upload the files, I don't have an easy way to generate an email saying "this uploaded file was for this field, and this uploaded file was for that field".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request.Files.Keys` is a collection of field names corresponding to each uploaded file.